# How to group rows with same time second in a python dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm working on a dataframe that contains a column of time (hh:mm:ss.zzz) and I'm looking for a solution to group all elements with similar seconds 'ss' .

Comment: Post your dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without posting your `DataFrame`, your question is difficult to answer, however this may be what you are after:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame([['ID1','01:22:52.134'],['ID2','03:21:31.123'],['ID3','21:12:52.544'],['ID4','23:12:31.216'],['ID5','10:22:02.134'],['ID6','06:52:46.184']], columns=["ID's",'Time'])

pattern = re.compile(r':(\d{2})\.')

dfout = df["ID's"].groupby(df['Time'].str.extract(pattern, expand=False))

for name, group in dfout:
    print('Group Name: ' + name)
    print(group)
```

Yields:

```
Group Name: 02
4    ID5
Name: ID's, dtype: object
Group Name: 31
1    ID2
3    ID4
Name: ID's, dtype: object
Group Name: 46
5    ID6
Name: ID's, dtype: object
Group Name: 52
0    ID1
2    ID3
Name: ID's, dtype: object
```

Comment: My dataframe contains multiple ids with correspondant timestamps. which means one column of ids and other column for time. what I want is to group all the ids that happened in the same second.

Comment: Edited my answer to account for your comment above. Please accept my answer with the green check mark if you feel this answered your question. Again, if would be helpful if you posted an example of your DataFrame in the OP to complete your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that was very helpful. still a little issue is that I want to consider hours and minutes also but stop in seconds and don't go further to microseconds. my time format is : %H:%M:%S.%f

Comment: I would encourage you to look into `regex` (regular expressions), and you can play around with the defined `pattern` in my answer above.

Comment: I tired with re.compile(r'(\d{0}):(\d{1}):(\d{2})\.') but it shows a problem of dimensions

Comment: Can you clarify more please ?

Comment: Well first off, what do you expect this to do: `\d{0}`? That is attempting to match 0 digits... I think you should take a look at some regular expression tutorials to get a better handle on their implementation

Comment: This may be more what you are after (only has a single capturing group): `pattern = re.compile(r'^(\d{2}(?:\:)\d{2}(?:\:)\d{2})\.')` See https://regex101.com/r/Q5stp2/1